# Receiving scalar error on Switch function when using related table

Tags: dax

Very new to DAX. Trying to use Switch for the first time. Getting 'he expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value'. I have been unable to figure out the solution. Here is the code:

```
IVC - Delivered Cubic Realization:=SWITCH(
    FILTER('Invoice Fact',RELATED('Product Dimension'[Product Family Code]) = "PL"),
    DIVIDE('Invoice Fact'[IVC - Delivered Amount Extended], 'Invoice Fact'[IVC - Cubic Conversion Footage]) * 1000
    ,DIVIDE('Invoice Fact'[IVC - Delivered Amount Extended], 'Invoice Fact'[IVC - Cubic Conversion Footage])
)
```

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to achieve here. The use of the RELATED Function in the DAX does not look appropriate.

Comment: If the Product Family Code on table Product Dimension table = "PL" the I want to divide the Delivered Amount Extended by the Cubic Conversion Footage from the Invoice Fact table and multiply it by 1000. If it is not "PL", then do the division but not multiply it by 1000.

Comment: Should have mentioned that the Invoice Fact table and the Product Dimension table are linked via a key field.

Comment: can you please provide sample data

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do what I needed:

IVC - Delivered Selling Realization:=VAR ProductFamily = SELECTEDVALUE('Product Dimension'[Product Family Code])
VAR ProductCategory = SELECTEDVALUE('Product Dimension'[Product Category Code])

RETURN
SWITCH(
TRUE(),
ProductFamily = "PL",
DIVIDE('Invoice Fact'[IVC - Delivered Amount Extended], 'Invoice Fact'[IVC - Billed Selling Footage]) * 1000,
ProductFamily = "VE",
DIVIDE('Invoice Fact'[IVC - Delivered Amount Extended], 'Invoice Fact'[IVC - Billed Selling Footage]) * 1000,
ProductFamily = "EWP" && ProductCategory = "BEAM",
DIVIDE('Invoice Fact'[IVC - Delivered Amount Extended], 'Invoice Fact'[IVC - Billed Selling Footage]) * 1000,
ProductFamily = "LU" && ProductCategory = "CORE",
DIVIDE('Invoice Fact'[IVC - Delivered Amount Extended], 'Invoice Fact'[IVC - Billed Selling Footage]) * 10,
DIVIDE('Invoice Fact'[IVC - Delivered Amount Extended], 'Invoice Fact'[IVC - Billed Selling Footage])
)